# telerik RAD HTMLChart Label display NaN (not a number)

Tags: asp.net, telerik, rad, radhtmlchart

I have a chart that is getting data from a SQL database in codebehind. Everything displays correctly and the series have the correct number on hover.

It is a stacked bar with the Show totals work a round found on this site.

http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/chart-%28html5%29/details/displaying-grand-total-in-stacked-series-labels-and-pie-series-legend

I know the data coming from SQL is a number because I'm casting it to decimal.

The gTotal shows: "TL bbl: NaN"
If I just do TL bbls: #=dataItem.TotalRed# it shows undefined
Any Ideas?

code behind:

```
    Dim daFMChart As New SqlDataAdapter(SQLFM, Conn)
    daFMChart.Fill(DTFMChart)

    Me.ColumnChart.DataSource = DTFMChart
    Me.ColumnChart.DataBind()
```

The SQL data is this

```
+-------------------------------------------------+
| DateTime     TotalRed   TotalWhite       gTotal |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| 2016-03-25    20000        3             0.0001 |
| 2016-03-24    30000        2601          0.0001 |
| 2016-03-23    50000        45626         0.0001 |
| 2016-03-22    10000        55568         0.0001 |
| 2016-03-21    30000        54098         0.0001 |
| 2016-03-20    10000        51351         0.0001 |
| 2016-03-19    20000        21973         0.0001 |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

```
<ChartTitle Text="Daily Volume Total Per Meter">
    <Appearance Align="Right" Position="Top">
        <TextStyle Color="#999999" />
    </Appearance>
</ChartTitle>

<Legend>
    <Appearance Position="Right" Visible="true">
        <TextStyle Color="#999999" />
    </Appearance>
</Legend>

<PlotArea>
    <Series>

        <telerik:ColumnSeries Name="FM Red" DataFieldY="TotalRed" Stacked="true">
            <LabelsAppearance Visible="false"></LabelsAppearance>
            <Appearance>
                <FillStyle BackgroundColor="#ff1a1a"></FillStyle>

            </Appearance>
        </telerik:ColumnSeries>

        <telerik:ColumnSeries Name="FM White" DataFieldY="TotalWhite">
            <LabelsAppearance Visible="false"></LabelsAppearance>
            <Appearance>
                <FillStyle BackgroundColor="#bfbfbf"></FillStyle>
            </Appearance>
        </telerik:ColumnSeries>

        <telerik:ColumnSeries DataFieldY="gTotal" Stacked="true">
            <Appearance FillStyle-BackgroundColor="#DDD9C3"></Appearance>
            <LabelsAppearance Position="OutsideEnd">
                <TextStyle Color="#999999" />
                <TextStyle Margin="0" />
                <ClientTemplate>
                        TL bbls: #=dataItem.TotalRed + dataItem.TotalWhite#
                </ClientTemplate>
            </LabelsAppearance>

            <TooltipsAppearance Visible="false">
            </TooltipsAppearance>
        </telerik:ColumnSeries>

    </Series>
    <XAxis DataLabelsField="DateTime"></XAxis>
    <XAxis>
        <MajorGridLines Visible="false" />
        <MinorGridLines Visible="false" />
        <LabelsAppearance Step="1">
            <TextStyle Color="#999999" />
        </LabelsAppearance>
    </XAxis>

    <YAxis>
        <MajorGridLines Visible="true" Color="#555555" />
        <MinorGridLines Visible="false" />
        <LabelsAppearance Step="1">
            <TextStyle Color="#999999" />
        </LabelsAppearance>
    </YAxis>
</PlotArea>

<ChartTitle Text=""></ChartTitle>
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess what..... Its a Bug.

Does not work with a Date column for the X Axis.

What a pain in the balls that was to figure out.

Had to use 3|24 as a string.. Could not use 3/24

Comment: Could you format the Date column data in your VB code behind before you bind it to your RAD HtmlChart? Instead of doing it in the `<ClientTemplate>`